# Is it possible to assign waypoints at runtime to player or game object in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is that possible to assign way-points at runtime to player or gameObject in Unity?

I'm going to create a random number of players at runtime and create twice as more gameObjects or transforms as way-points for player or gameObject...

Is is possible to set way-points at runtime depending on nature or number of players?

Any suggestion or solution are welcome.